# handlebars partials are not seen

Tags: typescript, handlebars.js, nestjs, hbs

I need to import hbs to use partials, but `import * as hbs from "hbs"` doesn't work, I use nest.js

Error: The partial header could not be found

my code:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);

  app.setBaseViewsDir(join(__dirname, "..", "views"));
  app.setViewEngine("hbs");
  hbs.registerPartials(__dirname + "/views/partials");

  await app.listen(parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed this line `hbs.registerPartials(join(__dirname, "..", "/views/partials"));` and it worked